# Replace in files with pattern

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm an occasional user of regular expresions, and my knowledge of them is far from stellar.

I have the following text in several centenar of files:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[B]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[B]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[A] ...
```

A changes for every file, the previous three lines where inserted (replace in files).

What I'm trying to accomplish is make B become A on every file. Like:

```
"blah blah [B] more blah [A1]" => "blah blah [A1] more blah [A1]"
"blah blah [B] more blah [A2]" => "blah blah [A2] more blah [A2]"
...
"blah blah [B] more blah [An]" => "blah blah [An] more blah [An]"
```

Does anyone knows if it's possible and how to do it?

Thanks.

EDIT. I forgot to say that before and after the above text there are other lines of code, variable for every file. This is not the only text in the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using backreferences and disgregation of the matching expression I arrived to a working solution, that while it's large and ugly, does the job perfectly:

Match: `(IF EXISTS \(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys\.objects WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID\(N'\[dbo\]\.)(\[\w+\])('\) AND type in \(N'P', N'PC'\)\)\r\n    DROP PROCEDURE \[dbo\]\.)(\[\w+\])(\r\nGO\r\nCREATE PROCEDURE \[dbo\]\.)(\[\w+\])`

Replace: `$1$6$3$6$5$6`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a backreference:

Match:
`([A-Za-z0-9\s]+) \[\w+\] ([A-Za-z0-9\s]+) (\[\w+\])`

Replace:
`\1 \3 \2 \3`

The parenthesis capture their content, the \n's play it back.
`[A-Za-z0-9\s]+` should match most of your SQL statments, and `\[\w+\]` should match the bits in square brackets.

Comment: Thanks. Your matching expression does not get any result. Could be because you expect only the above text in the file?